# connecting linux computer using vnc

Tags: linux, vnc, ports

I'm trying to connect to a linux computer using a vnc viewer, but the connection times out.
when I type `netstat -na`, none of the ports listed are 5900, which as I understood is the one VNC uses.
Is it possible? Or have I misunderstood something important on the way?
Anyway, the actual question is, what can I do in order to connect to my computer?

EDIT: I'm sorry I didn't mention this in the first place. The linux computer is a remote server which has some vncserver installed on.

Comment: So what VNC server have you installed on the Linux computer? How did you install it? Can you connect to the VNC server on the Linux computer itself?

Comment: On which computer did you use `netstat` (it should be run on the server). Are both computers able to access the network? Does a simple `ping` between them succeed?

Comment: no I couldn't `ping` them, the connection would just time out,

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you have installed and configured a vncserver on your linux properly.
vncserver by default will listen on port 5900+N , which N is the number of the output display. For example , if the output display number is 1 , then the port will be 5901.

Anyway, to connect to your linux computer, you first need to install and configure a vncserver such as tightvncserver as below (assuming your linux platform is deb base):

```
sudo apt install -y tightvncserver
```

After that, start the vncserver with the command:

```
vncserver
```

Then enter a password for connection. After that check if the vncserver is listening on the port 5900+N (5901 in most cases for the first vncserver display output). I usually check this with nmap. Make sure nmap is installed, or install it with

```
sudo apt install nmap
```

then check with:

```
nmap localhost
```

If vncserver is listening on 5900+N , then we are good to go.

For connecting to your vncserver, you can use any vncviewer (such as xtighvncviewer). Assuming the port is 5901, enter the address "server-ip:5901" (e.g. "192.168.1.2:5901") for the remote host. Then use the password you created above for vncserver to connect to your server.

Comment: vncserver was already installed. Plus, I'm not an Admin so I can't do about half of the stuff you mentioned. But, when I used `nmap localhost` there where three ports which probably belong to some other users, and mine [5904] isn't showed.

Comment: So you mean, after **ssh**ing into the remote server and executing `nmap localhost` or `netstat -na` on the _remove server_ , no vncserver was listening on the port 5904 which is the port you are supposed to connect via?

Comment: That's whet I meant. Now I doubled checked it and saw it is listening but instead of stating the service as `vnc-4` [I used `nmap localhost`], it says `unknown`.